# How can I know if there are any active threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a console application that when it is running sends emails through googles smtp client.

Code for this:

```
private void SendEmailThread(MailMessage message)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(() => _mailService.SendEmail(message));
    thread.Start();
    thread.Join();
}
```

How do I know when all threads are completed?

Is there a global property that is set to `ThreadsRunning = 0` when all are done?

I would like to send a message to the console when all emails have been sent and that is done when I have no more threads.

Something like:

```
if(allThreadsDone){
    Console.WriteLine("All mails are sent");
}
```

Comment: See these questions: [Suspending and notifying threads when there is work to do](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210020/suspending-and-notifying-threads-when-there-is-work-to-do) and [C# equivalent to java's wait and notify?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209281/c-sharp-equivalent-to-javas-wait-and-notify). Also look at [`Task.Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run.aspx) if you don't want a dedicated email sender thread.

Comment: From the looks of it your code is essentially the same as `_mailService.SendEmail(message);` because you use `Join` which waits on the thread to complete.

Comment: From MSDN: Blocks the calling thread until the thread represented by this instance terminates, while continuing to perform standard COM and SendMessage pumping.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder SendEmailThread method is called inside a loop. In other words I want it to be able to conntinue to the next email even if the current one has a delay or if something fails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is actually (more or less) running synchronously. This is because [`Thread.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta(v=vs.110).aspx) blocks the calling thread until the other thread ends. Or as MSDN puts it:

> Blocks the calling thread until the thread represented by this instance terminates, while continuing to perform standard COM and **SendMessage** pumping.

So essentially all you need to do is after the last call to `SendEmailThread` just print your message:

```
Console.WriteLine("All mails are sent");
```

For what you are trying to achieve I suggest you look into [`Task.WhenAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall(v=vs.110).aspx). In your case something like:

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (var message in messages)
{
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => _mailService.SendEmail(message)));
}

Task waiter = Task.WhenAll(tasks);
try
{
   waiter.Wait();
}
catch {}   

if (waiter.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
{
    Console.WriteLine("All messages sent.");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Some messages failed to send.");  
}
```

Comment: Was a bit fast to accept this. tried your soloution and it does not work. I am using SendAsync method of the smptp client and the code above executes before the messages are actualy sent

Comment: @Ra3IDeN The code above is an example of how to do what you are wanting. You never specified the methods were `async` in your question, in future provide an [MCVE]. As I have no idea what the rest of your code looks like this is an example of how to do this, I'm sure you can tailor it to your own needs. As is mentioned a lot here, this is not a code writing service.

Comment: Never expected a code service for this m8. Was as I asked in the question looking for a way to know if all my threads are done. 
Did not think I needed more code then what I provided

Comment: @Ra3IDeN if the method is `async`, you should `await` on it in the `Task` though I haven't ventured to much into those areas so I am unable to help you much further.